# Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Data_Form_Element_Weight' on line 144

Tags: error

I can't edit or add my products, the following error is being shown:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Data_Form_Element_Weight' not found in /home/youvesaved_ps/youvesaved.com/lib/Varien/Data/Form/Abstract.php on line 144
```

What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

That is because probably you don't have Varien_Data_Form_Element_Weight class, at least it is not present in default magento install.
Which means that probably you have used an extension which had added 'weight' as frontend input for attribute 'weight' and possibly provided the class to render it. Then it was removed and now database value is wrong and produces the error.

Check your eave_attribute table and filter by frontend_input='weight'.
If you find such entry, try changing the value to 'text' for example.